# Submitting the same paper to more than one conference in economics

Tags: conference, economics, paper-submission

I am aware of the post relating to this topic [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/51/submitting-the-same-research-to-multiple-conferences). However, it doesn't say anything for the paper relating to the economics. I would be glad if seasoned econ colleagues could clear out the confusion in this regard.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to believe the answer would be different for the field of economics?

Comment: Yes, because I didn't see any restrictions clause on the calls. However, I want to make sure whether this implies that it is ethically acceptable.

Comment: I wouldn't expect to see a restriction on the calls; they don't list all possibly types of bad behavior, with the disclaimer, "don't do this." Looking at [the site in the linked question](http://publicationethics.org/), there are a [number of economics journals who are members of the organization](http://publicationethics.org/members/e); I would imagine that would be demonstration enough that this behavior is universally recognized as unethical.

Comment: The "duplicate"'s answer appears to say that doing this is taboo, but in Economics academia it is perfectly common practice. I just returned from a conference where I saw some of the papers presented for the third or fourth time.

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt, ask the conference organizers about their policies. I have seen people give essentially the same talk at multiple conferences.